# With horizontal scroll in jquery Mobile in android

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

i"ve been hunting the docs and can't seem to find a way to make a scrollable horizontal navbar in jQuery mobile has anybody accomplished this yet ?

see i want something like valums.com/files/2009/menu/final.htm but just for a nav so you can swipe left or right to get to more menu items

guess this is what you want.

HTML.

```
<div class="categories">                
        <ul>                    
            <li><span><a href="">ABC</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">DEF</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">GHI</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">JKL</a></span></li>
        </ul>               
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){           
    var step = 1;
    var current = 0;
    var maximum = $(".categories ul li").size();
    var visible = 2;
    var speed = 500;
    var liSize = 120;
    var height = 60;    
    var ulSize = liSize * maximum;
    var divSize = liSize * visible; 

    $('.categories').css("width", "auto").css("height", height+"px").css("visibility", "visible").css("overflow", "hidden").css("position", "relative");
    $(".categories ul li").css("list-style","none").css("display","inline");
    $(".categories ul").css("width", ulSize+"px").css("left", -(current * liSize)).css("position", "absolute").css("white-space","nowrap").css("margin","0px").css("padding","5px");

    $(".categories").swipeleft(function(event){
        if(current + step < 0 || current + step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
            current = current + step;
            $('.categories ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".categories").swiperight(function(){
        if(current - step < 0 || current - step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
            current = current - step;
            $('.categories ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
        }
        return false;
    });         
});
```

but not able to get it can someone help me on it...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a carousel. I can not find any official support for it in jquery mobile. Sencha touch does have an implementation of one.

If you look http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-carousel-sencha-style somebody has tried to make a library to replicate this. See their demo here http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/

Alternatively you could try use an existing jquery/javascript carousel and get it to work on jquery mobile. I do know sequence.js ( http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/modern-slide-in/ ) supports touch events, and is very adaptable to whatever you want, with whatever transitions you want. So that may be a good one to try.

Edit:

I googled a bit and found: http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index2.html which seems to be the same type of thing as the one you linked, though this one supports touch events